# Trig function in complex analyis

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> Problem: Find $z$ such that $\tan z = \frac{i}{2}, \tan z=\frac{\sin
>  z}{\cos z}$

My attempt: $\tan z$ defined when $\cos z \neq 0$ i.e. $z\neq \pi/2$

$$
\frac{\sin z}{\cos z}=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}\cdot\frac{2}{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{i(e^{iz}+e^{-iz})}= \frac{i}{2}
$$

$2(e^{iz}-e^{-iz})=-(e^{iz}+e^{-iz})$ hence $3e^{iz}-e^{-iz}=0 $. Multiple both sides by $e^{iz}$, we have  $3e^{i2z}-1=0\implies e^{2iz}= \frac{1}{3}$. That gives us $2iz = \ln (1/3)$

But 
$$\ln(1/3) =|\ln (1/3)|e^{iarg (1/3) }= \ln(1/3)( \cos (\pi/2) + i\sin (\pi/2) ) = i \ln (1/3)
$$

Hence $2iz = i\ln (1/3)\implies z =\frac{\ln (1/3)}{2}$

But then z is real, and $\tan z \neq \frac{i}{2}$

I do not know where I messed it up. When I take $\tan z$, it is not equal $\frac i2$, still. Please, help me out.

Comment: $$\log(a+ib)=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\cdot e^{i\text{arg}(a+ib)}$$

Comment: @User73195 After "But..." you start with $ln(1/3)$ and you end that line with $iln(1/3)$ How is that right? From your previous line $2iz=ln(1/3)$ you could solve it for $z$ already to become $z=\frac{iln3}{2}$ Wouldn't that work?

Answer (score 1):

You actually calculated everything all right but indeed messed up one step, so let's start from the beginning, until
\begin{align}
\tan z=\frac{\sin z}{\cos z}=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}\cdot\frac{2}{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{i(e^{iz}+e^{-iz})}= \frac{i}{2}\\
\iff\\  e^{2iz}= \frac{1}{3}
\end{align}
everything is correct. Now you would actually have to apply the complex logarithm which would give us if we focus on the principal logarithm 
$$
2iz=\log\frac13\iff z=-i\frac12\log\frac13=i\frac12\log3 \tag1
$$
and we are done. Your **mistake** occurred while performing the step $(1)$

> $$\ln(1/3) =|\ln (1/3)|e^{iarg (1/3) }= \ln(1/3)( \cos (\pi/2) + i\sin (\pi/2) ) = i \ln (1/3)$$

clearly the LHS and the RHS do not equal. The $\arg(\frac13)$ is $0$
$$
\boxed{\arg\left(\frac13\right)=0}
$$ 
so you really get for the complex logarithm in general
$$
e^w=z \iff w=\log|z|+i\arg(z+2n\pi)
$$